# Installing Google App Engine Python SDK with MacPorts

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, macports

I am trying to install the Google App Engine Python SDK with MacPorts.

I have Python 2.7 installed (with MacPorts), and I just installed the GAE SDK:

```
sudo port install py-googleappengine
```

Which seemed to install correctly. When I run Python, however,

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 13 2014, 15:13:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google.appengine.api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named appengine.api
```

I have verified that the Python being used is the one from MacPorts, and not Apple's Python:

```
$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
```

And I have found the file /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleappengine.pth which contains

```
/opt/local/share/google_appengine
```

which also exists.

I am not sure why the library cannot be imported. Any ideas?

*UPDATE*: the issue is that there is a conflict with "google/protobuf/" which uses the same namespace and eclipses the new google namespace (*sigh*, I thought namespaces were meant to avoid this...); when I delete the "google" folder that contains protobuf, and try to import google then it contains nothing. I am not sure what file I am missing in the clean-up.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior after installing GAE.  You don't use GAE in that way.

Instead, you need to:

1. Run your Python code on local host (e.g., via your web browser) after [enabling the dev server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver), or
2. Test your Python code using [nose-gae](https://github.com/Trii/NoseGAE).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But actually I am trying to write a standalone script that uses the remote api, and hence not an actual GoogleApp.